# I can't see quantity in database MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So when I seed database using this

```
const order = new Order({
      user: "5f2a57ed2a86fd47f48b2f0c",
      clothes: [
        {
          quantity: 2,
          _id: "5f2a58df2a86fd47f48b2f0d",
        },
      ],
      shoes: [
        {
          quantity: 1,
          _id: "5f2a58df2a86fd47f48b2f0e",
        },
      ],
      confirmOrder: false,
    });

    order.save((error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Order saved successfully");
      }
    });
```

using this scheme

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const orderSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  clothes: [
    {
      quantity: Number,
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Clothe",
    },
  ],
  shoes: [
    {
      quantity: Number,
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Shoe",
    },
  ],
  confirmOrder: Boolean,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

I can't see quantity for indivudal item in database I can only see this I don't know should I try adding quantity to everypiece of clothing individualy or what?

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW6NA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW6NA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` field in the seed data is not defined in the scheme.

Try explicitly defining quantity and _id separately like:

```
shoes: [
  { 
    quantity: Number,
    _id: {
           type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Shoe"
    }
  }
]
```